# Shrinkwrap a curve without affecting its geometry?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

**I'm trying to create a "cable" (i want to animate the start/end-point of it later) on a surface.**

As you can see the shrinkwrap modifier is doing a pretty good job:
[image: Shrinkwrapped Curve]

But as soon i try to bevel the curve it looks completely destroyed:
[image: Shrinkwrapped Curve with Bevel that looks very very bad]

Is there a way to maintain the curve without affecting the geometry?

Comment: Can't make proper answer but check this link for the right button https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?345309-Shrinkwrapping-a-curve-without-deformation